# Do i need to worry about session collisions using discord.py and sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, discord.py, python-asyncio

i was working on a discord bot using discord.py and I was using asyncio sqlalchemy for database management, i was following along using https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html

I was just wondering if it was possible for sqlalchemy to have session collisions, so for example I start a session using `async with session.begin()` and in that context manager, I await something and the event loop jumps to another function and calls out another transaction when the previous one wasnt completed.

A pretty cheesy example of this would be

```
async def transaction(session):
    print("transaction begin")
    async with session.begin():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("transaction end")


async def start():
    engine = create_async_engine(connector)
    session =  sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_= AsyncSession)()
    await asyncio.wait( [transaction(session), transaction(session), transaction(session) ] )

asyncio.run(start())
```

My first question is that is this even possible with discord.py, does the event loop work that way? and secondly, if it does work that way, what are some methods to prevent it?